# Javascript - Why isn't this setTimeout function working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

For the life of me I cannot seem to get any kind of results from this snippet. I want the function to add and then remove an additional class to all elements with the id of `"ring"` with an added delay after each execution. Other examples of the `setTimeout()` function have it written like this.

```
function flash_rings()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("ring");
    setTimeout(function(){e.className = "ring hover";}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){e.className = "ring";}, 1000);
}
```

The class has been written and tested, so I know it's not fault of the CSS. The function is due to be called in the `<body>`'s `onload=` event. The snippet of code is located at the very bottom of the page, immediately above the `</body>` tag.

Help?

Thanks,

~Zion

Comment: Both events happend at the same time

Comment: I think you need to look into how asynchronous calls work in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Pablo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856808/javascript-why-isnt-this-settimeout-function-working?nah=1#comment45979654_28856808), they happen one right after another, one second later.

If you want the second to happen a second *after* the first:

```
function flash_rings()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("ring");
    setTimeout(function(){
        e.className = "ring hover";
        setTimeout(function(){
            e.className = "ring";
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Or

```
function flash_rings()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("ring");
    setTimeout(function(){ e.className = "ring hover"; }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ e.className = "ring"; }, 2000);
}
```

That latter one is a bit less connected, but you can be fairly sure the second one will happen *roughly* a second after the first, barring the page being really busy doing other things. (You wouldn't do that if the first weren't *also* a timer thing; if it were ajax or something, you'd definitely wait for the first to complete before scheduling the second.)

Comment: This resolved my issue. Thank you so much.

I would have thought the function would wait until completion before executing the next, but I'm used to Sleep (pausing the script), rather than executing a function after time.

Answer (score 0):

They both fire off almost in the same instance. One Timeout will not be waiting for another. Just change that second to 2000:

```
setTimeout(function(){e.className = "ring";}, 2000);
```